# Проверка наличия текста с помощью "Assert"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно проверить наличие одной строки на странице.
Раньше это было доступно способом: `Assert.assertTrue("Пример такста", true);`
Сейчас этот метод не работает. Я могу написать что попало и он все равно пишет, что найдено.
Метод `getPageSource.equals("Пример текста")` тоже не работает.

Подскажите пожалуйста еще варианты.
Спасибо

Comment: Посмотрите откуда импортируется Assert. Вероятно вы подцепили JUnut, а там проверка будет выглядеть несколько иначе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
Assert.IsTrue(verifyTextPresent("Ваш текст"));
```

Можно это выражение обвернуть в try/catch конструкцию что бы точно знать не находится текст или не выполняется код

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверить, что поиск элемента по xpath **.//*[contains(text(), "ваш текст")]** не вызывает ошибки *(или не возвращает null или какие там еще могут быть варианты для библиотеки на которой вы пишите)*. В случае ошибки логично предположить, что элемента с таким текстом на странице нет

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант попробуйте:

`Boolean check = Assert.assertTrue("Пример текста" == "Пример текста")`;

Если будут равны - будет `true`
Почитайте как работает `assertTrue`